# String formatting: negative/positive floating point numbers

Tags: c#, .net, string, double, string-formatting

How can I use `String.Format` in C# so doubles are displayed like this:

`example:

___-1.000

____1.000

__100.123

-1000.321

_1000.214`

etc...

Where _ is space (`" "`);

All I can do is `String.Format("{0:F3}", -123.321);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use alignment:

```
String.Format("{0,10:F3}", -123.321)
```

where 10 is preffered length.

See [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Found a quick article, in short:

```
String.Format("{0,10:0.0}", 123.4567);    // "     123.5"
String.Format("{0,-10:0.0}", 123.4567);   // "123.5     "
String.Format("{0,10:0.0}", -123.4567);   // "    -123.5"
String.Format("{0,-10:0.0}", -123.4567);  // "-123.5    "
```

Source: [Here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) <- Look here for more.