# Format Textbox c#

Tags: c#, textbox, format

I have this code

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     textBox_Machine_X_Axis.Text = adsClient.ReadAny(ActPos_X, typeof(Double)).ToString();
     ...
```

The output looks like this:

`2489.24544554444`        or           `-654.1`

Now the question,  how do i format this code so the output looks like this      `2489.245`       or        `-0654.100`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String formatting: negative/positive floating point numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356185/string-formatting-negative-positive-floating-point-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use string.format method , like this:

```
string.Format("{0:0000.000}", -654.1)
```

changing your original code, it will be something like this:

```
textBox_Machine_X_Axis.Text = string.Format("{0:0000.000}", adsClient.ReadAny(ActPos_X, typeof(Double)));
```

Comment: Mark it as answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the format in the .ToString() method like this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBox_Machine_X_Axis.Text = adsClient.ReadAny(ActPos_X, typeof(Double)).ToString("0000.000");
}
```

Check out this [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) for more info.